# How does the c2dm application push to the Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-c2dm

I am new in Android and trying to develop an app with push notification. I have a small confusion on the architecture behind the c2dm, that after getting the authentication token and device reg_Id, the application server will send them along with the message, but how will the server will know to send the message to the c2dm server?

I am getting an error and even I am not able to add a google account on my emulator for synchronization. While doing this my emulator says `com.android.calender not there`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: android: app -> reg app on google server -> if ok reg on your server(1) ...
your server: authnticate on google server -> send message to google server (Registration ID taken from point(1)) then on device: app getting your message from google server  .... so where is problem ?

Comment: @Jakub         I undrstood the concept but the thing is while registaring the device on google, I am getting an error andeven I am not able to add a google account on my emulator for synchronization. While doing this my emulator says com.android.calender not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call web service to sent push notification on particular device. And whatever the massage you want to pass on device is written in web service. you can make web service any any language like php or .net. Ask me if you have any query regarding push.